# How to share photo to Facebook on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried to share a image on Facebook but i can't. This is the code that I'm using:

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController * fbSheetOBJ = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock =
    ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        [fbSheetOBJ dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    };
    fbSheetOBJ.completionHandler = myBlock;

    [fbSheetOBJ addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com"]];
    [fbSheetOBJ setInitialText:@"Post from my iOS application"];
    [fbSheetOBJ addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.jpeg"]];

    [self presentViewController:fbSheetOBJ animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that, [UIImage imageNamed:@"download.jpeg"] is there. Check if ([UIImage imageNamed:@"download.jpeg"]) by this

Answer (score 0):

if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

```
            NSString *desc = @"the Text what you want to post in in facebook";                
            [mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourLink"]];
            [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:desc];
            //convert any type of image to png format
```

//Image url to post in facebook.

NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.imageurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

```
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            UIImage *pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];



            // image convertion ends..

            [mySLComposerSheet addImage:  image];

            [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

                switch (result) {
                    case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:

                     alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancelled" message:@"You Cancelled posting the Deal." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                        [alert show];
                        [alert release];
                        break;
                    case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:

                      alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"The Deal was posted successfully." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                        [alert1 show];
                        [alert1 release];
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }];

            [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```

Comment: how to convert image to url

Comment: Either you want to share local images or from internet

Comment: if it is local image you can convert into NSData  and then you can send it.

Comment: If PNG image

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your image name.png"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
If JPG image

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your image name.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

```
            NSString *desc = @"the Text what you want to post in in facebook";                
            [mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourLink"]];
            [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:desc];
            //convert any type of image to png format
```

//Image url to post in facebook.

NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.imageurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

```
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            UIImage *pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];



            // image convertion ends..

            [mySLComposerSheet addImage:  image];

            [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

                switch (result) {
                    case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:

                     alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancelled" message:@"You Cancelled posting the Deal." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                        [alert show];
                        [alert release];
                        break;
                    case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:

                      alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"The Deal was posted successfully." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                        [alert1 show];
                        [alert1 release];
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }];

            [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```